# How to add new outlet types to Xcode user interface?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, iboutlet

I'm trying to use the *[PWAutoLayout project](https://github.com/depth42/AutolayoutExtensions)* which adds a new type of Outlet to Xcode's user interface. When I open the PWAutoLayout sample project the new outlet named `PWHidingMasterView` is shown on the Xcode UI for UIViews and derived classes.

However, when I add the *PWAutoLayout* source files to my project, the outlet doesn't appear for the UIViews in my storyboard. They were added to my target, and I tried importing the headers: no difference.

What I am missing? How can one declare new outlet types for display in Xcode UI?

Comment: Have you set the class for the UIView to the appropriate PWAutoLayout class?

Comment: It's an extension for UIView rather than a subclass.

Comment: Oh, yeah I see now after looking at the PWAutoLayout git. Glad it got sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the difference: my project is inside a Workspace and the new outlet won't show there. If I open the project directly, the PWHidingMasterView outlet is there.

I reported this bug to Apple. I suggest you do the same if it affects you.